# Configure ACL on spark with zookeeper

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zookeeper, acl

I have configured spark to use zookeeper as RECOVERYMODE for high availability. We need to enable ACLs on zookeeper with authentication. I have also configured spark to pass zookeeper client authentication but the nodes created by spark are not secure. How can I configure spark to secure or set ACLs on the nodes it creates in zookeeper?